# How do I get a list of every possible combination of product prices to reach a target cost?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, iteration

Suppose I have a list of three products (A, B C). Each Product has a price. Given a total cost, I want to find all the possible product combinations to equal exactly that cost.

So far I've tried stuff like:

```
for price in product:
    ret = []
    for i in range(int(totalCost / price), -1, -1):
        ret.append(i)
        for c in range(1, len(products)+1, 1):
            ret.append(int(products[c-1][1]/products[c][1]))
```

And here is where I get stuck. This will get me a list of possibilities, but it will only include the products that are later (than the current location) in the list. It won't wrap around to include the beginning, and thus, give me every possibility.

What do I need to do to get every possibility?

Comment: What does your `product` and `products` lists look like? And I'm not sure I understand your objective correctly. Suppose `A = 1`, `B = 2` and `C = 3`. Given `totalCost = 3`, you want to get `[[A,B],[C]]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def possibilities(available_products, target_price):
    if target_price == 0 or not available_products:
        return []
    this_price = available_products[0]
    remaining_products = available_products[1:]
    results = []
    for qty in range(1 + target_price / this_price):
        remaining_price = target_price - qty*this_price
        if remaining_price == 0:
            results.append([qty] + [0] * len(remaining_products))
        else:
            for option in possibilities(remaining_products, remaining_price):
                results.append([qty] + option)
    return results
```

That gives you:

```
pprint.pprint(possibilities([1, 2, 5], 10))
[[0, 0, 2],
 [0, 5, 0],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [2, 4, 0],
 [3, 1, 1],
 [4, 3, 0],
 [5, 0, 1],
 [6, 2, 0],
 [8, 1, 0],
 [10, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I should probably have `assert min(available_products) > 0 and target_price >= 0` after the initial `if` to catch invalid input.

Comment: This I'm sure works great, but I need it to work for floats as well. My failure to not mention that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you pass it an array of Decimals for `available_products` and a Decimal for `target_price`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The *itertools* module offers combinatoric generators to help with problems such as this:

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> prices = dict(a=10, b=15, c=8, d=2, e=5)
>>> total_cost = 20
>>> for r in range(1, 30):
        for t in combinations_with_replacement(prices, r):
                cost = sum(prices[p] for p in t)
                if cost == total_cost:
                        print t
```

Comment: That `for` loop will fail to give all possibilities if you change `total_cost` to, say, 40.

Comment: Just scan for more combinations.  The user needs to set a reasonable limit so that the run-time doesn't explode for non-trivial problems.

Comment: If you set it to 51, it works well. For my purposes I just need to change all cost to Decimal objects. Thank you @RaymondHettinger, it works well and you learned me a new module.

Comment: "it works well" with `51`?
For the `3, [1,2,3]` case, this solution (with 51) takes over 66 seconds to run whereas my solution takes 5ms.  And for `4, [1,2,3,4]` this takes over 16 minutes vs mine at 10ms.

Comment: The recursive solution by retracile is an algorithmically superior solution and it scales well.  The itertools version uses an exhaustive search without any pruning, so it makes the computer do a lot more work.  The virtues of the itertools version are that it took under a minute of programmer time to develop, it worked the first time, and it is trivial easy to see that it is correct.  I didn't even write a script for it -- the interactive prompt was sufficient for a problem this simple.