# A combinations_with_replacement function in fortran?

Tags: python, fortran, combinatorics, python-itertools

I wrote a small module in python for get all the possibilities of `x` products that fit into `y` total cost. The module runs fine, but slow. It takes about six hours to calculate six products up to 30 iterations of each product. So, I was thinking of rewriting the script in FORTRAN and see if I can't milk out some better speed. Unfortunately, I'm new to FORTRAN, and don't now most of the libraries and so on.

Is there a similar module/function to python's `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(pool, r)` in FORTRAN, or module that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that.  You are trying to do micro-optimization when you need to be doing algorithmic optimization.  This is why I argued you [should not use the exponential-time solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825323/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-every-possible-combination-of-product-prices-to-reach-a-t/7825490#7825490) based on itertools, but a [better, recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825323/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-every-possible-combination-of-product-prices-to-reach-a-t/7825718#7825718).

Comment: I agree with retracile.  If you don't truly need to look over all possible combinations with replacement, then it is worth avoiding.  Also, CPython's combinations_with_replacent is written in C so you're not a going to gain speed by rewriting that part in Fortran (though you can gain speed on the the actions that you take for each combination).

Comment: Indeed, you are correct sir. Thank you for setting me straight. Do you by change know how to calculate the number of iterations required? Even with you method I'm still taking a good long time. Minutes instead of hours, but still worthy of a progress bar.

Comment: I think your next step would be to step back and think about what you are using the results for.  There may be room for further optimization if you don't have to have every possibility.  Also, the example implementation I have could be improved by converting it to a generator.  (It's trivial to do, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) has a pure python equivalent for combinations_with_replacement().  It is succinct and shouldn't be hard to translate into Fortran

```
def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    # combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that. I was just looking to not rewrite the wheel. ;-P