# Finding a sequence from given numbers that sum to given value?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a set of integers (positive or negative), how can I find a sequence of these numbers that sum to given value?

Example: Given a list of numbers `[4,-16, 9, 33]`, I need the sum `17`. I can choose sequence `[4, 4, 9]`(numbers can be reused) or `[-16, 33]`. I'm trying to find an efficient way to reduce the length of the sequence.

It's like `Subset Sum Problem` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum) but in my case numbers can be reused.

It's also a little like the Partition problem ([Find all possible subsets that sum up to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330371/find-all-possible-subsets-that-sum-up-to-a-given-number)) but in my case there's negative values.

My current greedy algorithm as follows. In each loop I'll try to find a number that minimize the difference between the current sum and target sum.

```
integers = [-2298478782, 1527301251, 4, 4078748803, 3388759435,
        1583071281, 2214591602, 1528349827, -12, 59460983,
        -939524100, -1, 2315255807]
target_sum = 1997393191

difference = target_sum
chain = list()
while difference != 0:
    min_abs_difference = abs(difference)
    next_int = 0
    found = False
    for i in integers:
        new_abs_diff = abs(i+difference)
        if new_abs_diff < min_abs_difference:
            found = True
            next_int = i
            min_abs_difference = new_abs_diff
    if not found:
        print(difference)
        print(chain)
        print("Cannot find an integer that makes difference smaller")
        break
    difference += next_int
    chain.append(next_int)
print(chain)
```

Comment: It seems you have a solution. Are you trying to achieve a certain complexity or reduce requirements or something?

Comment: @WaleedKhan It's a greedy algorithm so it may not give the optimal solution. I hope someone can give me a better solution which may either faster (mine was pretty slow) or give an optimal solution.

Comment: I don't think the present algorithm takes all the possibilities into consideration.

Comment: you need to brute force it ... afaik theres no sweet algorithm for this

Comment: @AbhishekBansal No it doesn't. It's just a greedy algorithm that make choice based on the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

There most likely isn't a fast algorithm that gives an optimal solution. The subset-sum problem is NP-complete and that problem is easier than your problem (because you allow reuse of numbers).

Given that the problem is NP-complete I think you should focus on improving your current algorithm or rewrite it in a faster language such as C. You can then call your C code from Python.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try `Cython` to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is obviously at least NP complete problem you can think of formulating it as a Mixed Integer Linear Programming Problem.

```
Minimize summation( Xi ) // Xi = number of times the array element Ai is used.
Subject To
     summation( Ai*Xi ) = S.
     Xi >= 0 { Xi are all integers }
```

You can solve it using any solver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not familiar with Mixed Integer Linear Programming except for the wiki page of `Integer_programming`. Would you mind give some pages that's suitable for newbies?

Comment: it's not obvious how one would prove NP-hardness. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12273. Do you have a proof sketch or some biblio ref for this problem?