# Find all possible combinations/partitions of 2 numbers for a given number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found this code on the Internet ([Find all possible subsets that sum up to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330371/find-all-possible-subsets-that-sum-up-to-a-given-number))

```
def partitions(n):
        if n:
            for subpart in partitions(n-1):
                yield [1] + subpart
                if subpart and (len(subpart) < 2 or subpart[1] > subpart[0]):
                    yield [subpart[0] + 1] + subpart[1:]
        else:
            yield []
```

I was wondering if someone could find a way to pull out of the answer only the answers, that are 2 digit addition?

For example: I type in 10. It gives me:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4] , [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 4, 4], [2, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 2 , 6], [2, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], [4, 6], [1, 1, 1, 7], [1, 2, 7], [3, 7], [1, 1, 8], [2, 8], [1, 9], [10]]
```

I would like it only gives:

```
[[5, 5], [4, 6], [3, 7], [2, 8], [1, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

n = 10
print([x for x in combinations_with_replacement(range(1,n), 2) if sum(x) == n])

[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! It even works fast compared to the last one :)

Comment: would you know how I could make this into something that I could split each section of the list into 2 then multiply them? I need that, this got harder than I thought.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean by splitting into groups of two?

Comment: I am using this to make a factoring polynomials calculator, you take the first number the "sum" then you multiply two numbers that sum up to get the "sum" and if they get the second number the "product" those are the numbers.

Comment: For example a^2+339a+26660, whereas +339 is the "sum" and 26660 is the "product", when I sum 124 and 215 I get 339 and when I multiply them I get 26660. Thanks

Comment: so you want all combinations of the sum* sum but with replacement?

Comment: so I want it so that if the product of the two numbers is equal to another number, lets call it p, then only it will print it out. (also if they add to get the first number, the "sum" lets call it s)

Comment: Combinatorial logic is an awful algorithm for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want partitions of length 2 (and the products of the elements of each partition), we can use a simpler approach:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Find pairs of positive integers that sum to n, and their product '''

def part_prod(n):
    parts = [(i, n-i) for i in xrange(1, 1 + n//2)]
    print parts    
    print '\n'.join(["%d * %d = %d" % (u, v, u*v) for u,v in parts])


def main():    
    n = 10
    part_prod(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)]
1 * 9 = 9
2 * 8 = 16
3 * 7 = 21
4 * 6 = 24
5 * 5 = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with list comprehension without using `itertools`.

```
num = 10
[[x, y] for x in range(1, num) for y in range(1, num) if x + y == num and x <= y]

# [[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5]]
```

Comment: Combinatorial logic is an awful algorithm for this. This is an improvement on Padraic Cunningham's answer but I still don't like it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: See PM 2Ring's answer.

Comment: Oh ya, agreed, way simpler.